# Python - Count how many times keywords stored in a list appear in text

Tags: python, nlp, keyword-search

I have a list KeywordList of 20k+ keywords. I want to check how many keywords in KeywordList appear in multiple, separate text files. I would also like to know the overall frequency of the keywords that appear in the text files. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You want to count how many times (for instance the word "the", etc..) occurs in many documents?

Comment: @Jab yes but only if the word is in KeywordList and occurs in any of the text files.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the bag of words approach: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model

here is an example I had a few years back, extracting word counts from a pandas dataframe:

```
all_words = df['keywords'].str.split(expand=True).unstack().value_counts()
```

this gives you a key-value pairing of unique words and their count. Iterate over your files and you should have all of the words with their counts

From there you can convert your keywords and KeywordList to sets and use the `intersection` function. This will produce you with a set of all keywords in KeywordList